# Access Photos of iOS Photos app using Meteor.js and Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

How can you select a photo from the Photos iOS app?

With `mdg:camera` installed, I only managed to get photos by taking them using the iPhone's camera. How can we select an existing photo from the Photos app?

```
var cameraOptions = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600
};

MeteorCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function (error, data) {
    console.log('photo: ', data)
});
```

Comment: This might help http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/07/23/better-example-of-phonegap-parse-and-uploading-files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just published a post regarding this...

Basically all you have to do is add sourceType to your cameraOptions, like so:

```
var cameraOptions = {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
};
```

**Note: ** this will only work when using Cordova.

Original Post: http://differential.com/blog/access-the-photo-library-in-your-meteor-cordova-app

Demo Repo: https://github.com/spencercarli/meteor-cordova-photolibrary

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both, you can use:

```
meteor add okland:camera-ui
```

And use the method called and send the same options:

```
var cameraOptions = {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
 };
MeteorCameraUI.getPicture(cameraOptions, callback)
```

camera-ui use mdg:camera so you can use the same options.